# C-Python asyncio: running discord.py in a thread

Tags: c, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, discord.py

I have to launch discord.py in a separate thread since I can't block my main thread.
It is a game server `C/Python 3.7 (ubuntu 18)`

**C code:**

```
int pysDiscord_Init;
...
PyObject *psv_discord;

psv_discord = Python_LoadModule("sv_discord");
if (psv_discord != NULL) {
  pysDiscord_Init = Python_RegisterFunction(psv_discord, "sv_discord", "init");
  Python_Execute(pysDiscord_Init, "");
}
```

**sv_discord.py**

```
import discord
import asyncio
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing

TOKEN = '12345'

client = discord.Client()

def init():
    print("Initializing Discord...")
    print("current_thread: %s" % threading.current_thread())
    t = threading.Thread(target=client.run, args=(TOKEN,))
    t.start()

or

def init():
    print("Initializing Discord...")
    print("current_thread: %s" % threading.current_thread())
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    task = loop.run_in_executor(pool, client.run, TOKEN)
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

**set_wakeup_fd exception:**

```
...
Initializing Discord...
current_thread: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 4150019840)>

Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./build/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 92, in add_signal_handler
 ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./build/Lib/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
 File "./build/Lib/threading.py", line 865, in run
 File "./../source/discord.py-rewrite/discord/client.py", line 550, in run
 File "./build/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 94, in add_signal_handler
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
```

I should mention that I tried the same code on the python (without the C code) and it works.
This error tells me about the main thread. But I don't create `sv_discord` inside the new thread, and as you can see from the log, it is the `"Main"` thread inside `init()` method. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I should thank this source [asyncio-you-are-a-complex-beast](https://www.codependentcodr.com/asyncio-you-are-a-complex-beast.html) where I finally found a solution.
The final working code looks like this:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


client = discord.Client()


def init():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(client.start(TOKEN))
    Thread(target=loop.run_forever).start()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print("on_message content: %s, channel: %s" % (message.content, message.channel))
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')


@client.event
    async def on_ready():
    print("Discord bot logged in as: %s, %s" % (client.user.name, client.user.id))
```

My main mistake was that for the game I compiled and used the latest `rewrite` version while inside the system over the pip I got `0.16.12` and read the [documentation for 0.16.12](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) while I had to look at [discord.py.rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/) (for example inside `on_message` I used wrong `client.send_message` while I had to use `message.channel.send`)

Comment: For me, the critical bit was switching from `client.run` to `client.start` and changing the loop setup to `loop.create_task(start())` + `loop.run_forever`. I didn't use `get_child_watcher` and the code still runs just fine, as you noted. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @computerfreaker here is the working copy of the module that I've made for my server: [github](https://github.com/Igor-ua/python-shared/tree/master/sv_discord).

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar edge case *(not really the intended use of `asyncio` but what the hell)* where I needed to Thread the `discord.py` instance.

I ended up modifying your solution with the following:

```
class discordHost(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{DThread.discord_client.user} has connected.')

class Threader(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.start()

    async def starter(self):
        self.discord_client = discordHost()
        await self.discord_client.start(DISCORD_TOKEN)

    def run(self):
        self.name = 'Discord.py'

        self.loop.create_task(self.starter())
        self.loop.run_forever()

if not 'Discord.py' in [t.name for t in tenumerate()]:
    DThread = Threader()
```

This does more or less the same thing, but I've subclassed `Thread` and subclassed `discord.Client` to more easily work with the outcome of the two.

The **only** caveat here, is that `asyncio.get_event_loop()` has to be called **before** `Thread.start()`, otherwise it gets confused and losses it's context of the main thread.

Comment: How do you send commands to the client from another thread that holds the DThread object here?